# HTML5, WordPress and Tiny MCE issue - wrapping anchor tag around div results in funky output

Tags: tinymce, html5

So I'm using HTML5 on a website and am trying to wrap a div in an anchor tag, which is supposedly acceptable in HTML5 websites. But when I do this...

```
<a href="#mylink"><div class="some_class">Some content</div></a>
```

...through the WordPress Tiny MCE editor, I get this output:

```
<p><a href="#mylink">&nbsp;</a></p>
<a href="#mylink"><div class="some_class">Some content</div></a>
<p><a href="#mylink"></a></p>
```

All kinds of messed up. If I flip to the visual editor and back to Text in Tiny MCE, it has changed the code to this:

```
<a href="#mylink"> </a>
<div class="some_class">Some content</div>
&nbsp;
```

Does anyone know how to force Tiny MCE to allow this? (ideally without resorting to the advanced plugin version of Tiny MCE)

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: For reference: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22888

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the TinyMCE settings, specifically the [`valid_children`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children) setting. To accomplish this in Wordpress, use the [`tiny_mce_before_init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init) filter reference.

Something like this (untested):

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'modify_valid_children');

function modify_valid_children($settings){
    $settings['valid_children']="+a[div|p|ul|ol|li|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h5|h6]";
    return $settings;
}
```

You may be able to use +a[*] to capture all elements, but you'll want to take care to avoid [nested anchor tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2).

Comment: Thanks Matt but I still can't get this to work. FYI, I had to remove the `)` on line 6 - it errored otherwise

Comment: Ah, good catch. Looks like I've been writing too much jQuery lately. :) You should also remove the semi-colon. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Not sure if this will make a difference for you, but I don't suspect it will.

Comment: _Setting "valid_elements", "invalid_elements" and "extended_valid_elements" can be done through this filter._ from a [comment in the core file](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php#L443)

Comment: Why don't you use just a `<span>` or `<p>` instead of a `<div>`?